# MySQL: Count instances of values in several columns and get the result as a specially formatted table

Tags: mysql

I'm creating charts with Chartio and I need to retrieve some calculated values from my MySQL DB.

There is only one table, and it contains several columns holding a grade (this is imported from a CSV so it's a "flat database"). Column names are like so: 1a_grade, 1b_grade, 1c_grade, 2a_grade etc.

The value of each grade can be "0","1","2","3" and "-".

I would like to return a table that looks like:

```
+-----------+-------+-------+
| GradeName | Grade | Count |
+-----------+-------+-------+
| 1A        | 0     |     4 |
| 1A        | 1     |     9 |
| 1A        | 2     |     2 |
| 1A        | 3     |     8 |
| 1A        | -     |    19 |
| 1B        | 0     |     6 |
| 1B        | 1     |     2 |
| 1B        | 2     |     8 |
| 1B        | 3     |    10 |
| 1B        | -     |    24 |
+-----------+-------+-------+
```

(the count is just random numbers here)

The reason I want to have the table formatted this way is because this is (to my knowledge) the only way to make Chartio draw the chart correctly with the axises on the right places...

So far I've come up with:

```
SELECT 1a_grade, COUNT(*)
FROM opc_protocol
GROUP BY 1a_grade;
```

Which gives me:

```
+----------+----------+
| 1a_grade | COUNT(*) |
+----------+----------+
| -        |        1 |
| 0        |        6 |
| 1        |       32 |
+----------+----------+
```

(real counts)

The problem is that, since I don't yet have entries with value "2" or "3", I dont get rows for them when i GROUP BY 1a_grade. I want to group by the literals "0", "1", "2", "3" and "-".

The other problem is that I don't get the GradeName in a column.

The THIRD problem is that I can't get multiple grades :)

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Regards,
Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick I would use is UNION with a series of queries of each column.  Kind of tedious, but it works.  I reproduced your problem in mySQL by creating a grades table with the columns you suggested (1a_grade, 1b_grade, 1c_grade, 2a_grade, 2b_grade, 2c_grade).  I then populated it with about 70 records with somewhat random patterns of data values in each column (from the value domain of: -,0,1,2,3).

I then constructed the following query to display your output format:

```
SELECT '1A' as grade_name, `1a_grade` as `grade`, count(*) as `count`
    FROM grade
    GROUP BY '1A', `1a_grade`
UNION ALL
SELECT '1B' as grade_name, `1b_grade` as `grade`, count(*) as `count`
    FROM grade
    GROUP BY '1B', `1b_grade`
UNION ALL
SELECT '1C' as grade_name, `1c_grade` as `grade`, count(*) as `count`
    FROM grade
    GROUP BY '1C', `1c_grade`
UNION ALL
SELECT '2A' as grade_name, `2a_grade` as `grade`, count(*) as `count`
    FROM grade
    GROUP BY '2A', `2a_grade`
UNION ALL
SELECT '2B' as grade_name, `2b_grade` as `grade`, count(*) as `count`
    FROM grade
    GROUP BY '2B', `2b_grade`
UNION ALL
SELECT '2C' as grade_name, `2c_grade` as `grade`, count(*) as `count`
    FROM grade
    GROUP BY '2C', `2c_grade`
```

It produced the output format you want with 3 columns (grade_name, grade, count).

I hope this helps.

Comment: You're truly a saviour! This solution works right out of the box :) Thank you!